# Are there UI toolkits for Metro apps in Windows 7?

Tags: .net, windows-7, microsoft-metro

I know that the real Metro (erm, I mean Windows 8 UI Style) requires Windows 8 since it's based on WinRT, but I noticed that apps like GitHub for Windows have that Metro look.

Is there a library or UI toolkit for .net that offers Metro-lookalike for Windows 7/.net 4.0?

Comment: This is exactly the kind of question that is the most valuable.  It's a shame moderators feel there's no room for such.  Somewhere there needs to be an open-ended technical Q&A forum with voting on answers.

Comment: @Alan the problem is that these tend to get old and stale after a while. One can argue that it's very unlikely that the status quo of "Metro for Windows 7" will change, but now that I'm thinking about it I can see why this question isn't deemed suitable.

Comment: Me, I'm glad you asked and Bradley answered.

Answer (score 3):

[MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/) is a WPF library that can give Windows 7 apps a Metro appearance; it also provides some Metro-style common controls.

It's [available on NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/MahApps.Metro/) under the Microsoft Public License.